# How can I import glsl as string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, glsl

I am working at a WebGL project by TypeScript. There are many shaders written by glsl, and I want to import them as string in my ts file. Like:

```
import fxaa from "./shaders/fxaa";
const fxaaShader = new Shader(fxaa); // pass as string
```

Can I do it ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the shader file (`./shaders/fxaa`) looks like?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Late to the party here, but just add a declaration file `glsl.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.glsl' {
  const value: string
  export default value
}
```

...then import as string:

```
import shaderVert from './shaders/vertex.glsl'
```

...and if you're using webpack you'll need [`ts-shader-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-shader-loader)

Comment: This works great, but I'm curious why it only works when the module name starts with an asterisk (*). Is there any reason behind that behaviour?

Comment: Probably pretty late with this answer but this import will work for any file that has the `.glsl` extension, the * sign serves as the "all" selector meaning that it doesn't matter how your file is named as long as it has the proper extension.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on how the shader file (`./shader/fxaa`, in your example) is written.  If you are writing this shader file yourself, you could do something like this:

```
const fxaa = 'my shader code here';
export { fxaa };
```

And then use this shader code:

```
import { fxaa } from './shader/fxaa';
const fxaaShader = new fxaaShader(fxaa);
```

Alternatively, you could write the shader file (`./shader/fxaa.json`) like this:

```
"my shader code here"
```

And require this file as a JSON object:

```
const fxaa = require('./shader/fxaa.json');
const fxaaShader = new fxaaShader(fxaa);
```

Comment: It seems the best way to import glsl is to use loader of webpack/rollup...

Comment: You miss the whole point of the .glsl source being pure GLSL and editable (syntax highlight, error checking, and stuff) in an editor.